# Implementing correct php database access for login/register modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I am trying to redesign a login page to incorporate both login/register forms within the one page and not having 2 separate pages. Previously I had my login and register pages both correctly accessing my database via php. 
I have tried to simply copy the elements that I needed from what I previously had working for each individual but page for the tutorial below, however my database connection/php does not seem to be doing anything.

I'm following this method outlined at http://codyhouse.co/gem/loginsignup-modal-window/

**New index.php**

```
<?php

session_start();

?>

<?php


//Log out and delete cookie
 /* if(isset($_GET['logout'])){
            session_destroy();

  }*/

//After validation, then check the entered data  
  if( isset($_POST['log_username']) && isset($_POST['log_password'])) {


    $log_username = $_POST['log_username'];
    $log_password = $_POST['log_password'];

    $con =mysql_connect("localhost", "user4321", "4321");
    mysql_select_db('supernatural',$con);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_username='$log_username' AND user_password2='$log_password'";
    $sql_E = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_username='$log_username'";

    $loginShow = mysql_query($sql);
    $loginShow_E = mysql_query($sql_E);

    $lookOver=mysql_num_rows($loginShow);
    $lookOver_E=mysql_num_rows($loginShow_E);

    $row = mysql_fetch_array($loginShow);
    $row_E = mysql_fetch_array($loginShow_E);

    $myuser = $row['user_fn'];
    //$cookie_name = "cook_name";
    if($lookOver == 1){ 
            //Set Cookie for 1 day
            //setcookie($cookie_name,"$myuser", time() + 86400,"/");
            $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
            $_SESSION['user'] = $myuser;
            $_SESSION['userid'] = $row['user_id'];
            $_SESSION['userlevel'] = $row['level'];

            header("location: map.php");



            /*
if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
                echo "Cookie name does not exist!";
                } else {
                    echo "Cookie is named: <br>" . $_COOKIE[$cookie_name]."<a href='?logout'>Log Out</a>";

                    }
*/


        } else {
            //If only password is wrong, then it will send an email with password.
            if($lookOver_E == 1){

                echo "Don't remember your password? </br> <a class='refound_P' href='register.php'>Register a new account with a new email</a>";
                /*href='found.php '>Send me a email with my password.</a>";   */      
            //If there is not one data relevant to, then it requires users reset.
            }else{
                echo "</br>Don't remember your Username? </br> <a class='refound_E' href='register.php'>Register a new account with a new email</a>";

            }

            }


    mysql_close($con);

  }

  //echo json_encode($_SESSION['loggedin'] ? 'true' : 'false');


?>
<!--doctype html-->
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css"> <!-- CSS reset -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styleA.css"> <!-- Gem style -->
    <script src="js/modernizr.js"></script> <!-- Modernizr -->

    <title>Log In &amp; Sign Up Form</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header role="banner">
        <div id="cd-logo"><a href="#0"><img src="img/cd-logo.svg" alt="Logo"></a></div>

        <nav class="main-nav">
            <ul>
                <!-- inser more links here -->
                <li><a class="cd-signin" href="#0">Sign in</a></li>
                <li><a class="cd-signup" href="#0">Sign up</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <div class="cd-user-modal"> <!-- this is the entire modal form, including the background -->
        <div class="cd-user-modal-container"> <!-- this is the container wrapper -->
            <ul class="cd-switcher">
                <li><a href="#0">Sign in</a></li>
                <li><a href="#0">New account</a></li>
            </ul>

            <div id="cd-login"> <!-- log in form -->
                <form class="cd-form" action="index.php" method="post">
                    <p class="fieldset">
                        <label class="image-replace cd-username" for="log_username">Login</label>
                        <input class="full-width has-padding has-border" id="log_username" type="text" placeholder="Username">
                        <span class="cd-error-message">Please enter a username!</span>
                    </p>

                    <p class="fieldset">
                        <label class="image-replace cd-password" for="log_password">Password</label>
                        <input class="full-width has-padding has-border" id="log_password" type="password"  placeholder="Password">
                        <span class="cd-error-message">Please enter a password!</span>
                    </p>

                    <p class="fieldset">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="remember-me" checked>
                        <label for="remember-me">Remember me</label>
                    </p>

                    <!--p class="fieldset"-->
                        <input class="full-width" id="submitBtn" type="submit" value="Login">
                    <!--/p-->
                </form>

                <p class="cd-form-bottom-message"><a href="#0">Forgot your password?</a></p>
                <!-- <a href="#0" class="cd-close-form">Close</a> -->
            </div> <!-- cd-login -->






            <div id="cd-signup"> <!-- sign up form -->
                <form class="cd-form">
                    <p class="fieldset">
                        <label class="image-replace cd-username" for="signup-username">Username</label>
                        <input class="full-width has-padding has-border" id="signup-username" type="text" placeholder="Username">
                        <span class="cd-error-message">Error message here!</span>
                    </p>

                    <p class="fieldset">
                        <label class="image-replace cd-email" for="signup-email">E-mail</label>
                        <input class="full-width has-padding has-border" id="signup-email" type="email" placeholder="E-mail">
                        <span class="cd-error-message">Error message here!</span>
                    </p>

                    <p class="fieldset">
                        <label class="image-replace cd-password" for="signup-password">Password</label>
                        <input class="full-width has-padding has-border" id="signup-password" type="text"  placeholder="Password">
                        <a href="#0" class="hide-password">Hide</a>
                        <span class="cd-error-message">Error message here!</span>
                    </p>

                    <p class="fieldset">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="accept-terms">
                        <label for="accept-terms">I agree to the <a href="#0">Terms</a></label>
                    </p>

                    <p class="fieldset">
                        <input class="full-width has-padding" type="submit" value="Create account">
                    </p>
                </form>

                <!-- <a href="#0" class="cd-close-form">Close</a> -->
            </div> <!-- cd-signup -->

            <div id="cd-reset-password"> <!-- reset password form -->
                <p class="cd-form-message">Lost your password? Please enter your email address. You will receive a link to create a new password.</p>

                <form class="cd-form">
                    <p class="fieldset">
                        <label class="image-replace cd-email" for="reset-email">E-mail</label>
                        <input class="full-width has-padding has-border" id="reset-email" type="email" placeholder="E-mail">
                        <span class="cd-error-message">Error message here!</span>
                    </p>

                    <p class="fieldset">
                        <input class="full-width has-padding" type="submit" value="Reset password">
                    </p>
                </form>

                <p class="cd-form-bottom-message"><a href="#0">Back to log-in</a></p>
            </div> <!-- cd-reset-password -->
            <a href="#0" class="cd-close-form">Close</a>
        </div> <!-- cd-user-modal-container -->
    </div> <!-- cd-user-modal -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script> <!-- Gem jQuery -->
</body>
</html>
```

**The new main.js**

```
$(window).load(function(){
    var $form_modal = $('.cd-user-modal'),
        $form_login = $form_modal.find('#cd-login'),
        $form_signup = $form_modal.find('#cd-signup'),
        $form_forgot_password = $form_modal.find('#cd-reset-password'),
        $form_modal_tab = $('.cd-switcher'),
        $tab_login = $form_modal_tab.children('li').eq(0).children('a'),
        $tab_signup = $form_modal_tab.children('li').eq(1).children('a'),
        $forgot_password_link = $form_login.find('.cd-form-bottom-message a'),
        $back_to_login_link = $form_forgot_password.find('.cd-form-bottom-message a'),
        $main_nav = $('.main-nav');

    //open modal
    $main_nav.on('click', function(event){

        if( $(event.target).is($main_nav) ) {
            // on mobile open the submenu
            $(this).children('ul').toggleClass('is-visible');
        } else {
            // on mobile close submenu
            $main_nav.children('ul').removeClass('is-visible');
            //show modal layer
            $form_modal.addClass('is-visible'); 
            //show the selected form
            ( $(event.target).is('.cd-signup') ) ? signup_selected() : login_selected();
        }

    });

    //close modal
    $('.cd-user-modal').on('click', function(event){
        if( $(event.target).is($form_modal) || $(event.target).is('.cd-close-form') ) {
            $form_modal.removeClass('is-visible');
        }   
    });
    //close modal when clicking the esc keyboard button
    $(document).keyup(function(event){
        if(event.which=='27'){
            $form_modal.removeClass('is-visible');
        }
    });

    //switch from a tab to another
    $form_modal_tab.on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        ( $(event.target).is( $tab_login ) ) ? login_selected() : signup_selected();
    });


    //show forgot-password form 
    $forgot_password_link.on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        forgot_password_selected();
    });

    //back to login from the forgot-password form
    $back_to_login_link.on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        login_selected();
    });

    function login_selected(){
        $form_login.addClass('is-selected');
        $form_signup.removeClass('is-selected');
        $form_forgot_password.removeClass('is-selected');
        $tab_login.addClass('selected');
        $tab_signup.removeClass('selected');
    }

    function signup_selected(){
        $form_login.removeClass('is-selected');
        $form_signup.addClass('is-selected');
        $form_forgot_password.removeClass('is-selected');
        $tab_login.removeClass('selected');
        $tab_signup.addClass('selected');
    }

    function forgot_password_selected(){
        $form_login.removeClass('is-selected');
        $form_signup.removeClass('is-selected');
        $form_forgot_password.addClass('is-selected');
    }

    //$form_login.find('input[id="submitBtn"]').on('click', function(event){
        //validate();
//console.log("YO");
        //event.preventDefault();

$('#submitBtn').click(function(){
        var loginUsername = $('#log_username');
        var loginPass = $('#log_password');
        var logintext = false;
        var passwordtext = false;
        if (loginUsername.val() != 0){
        loginUsername.removeClass('has-error').next('span').removeClass('is-visible');
        logintext = true;
        } else {
            loginUsername.addClass('has-error').next('span').addClass('is-visible');
                logintext = false;  
                    //console.log("NO");
        }

        if (loginPass.val() != 0){
        loginPass.removeClass('has-error').next('span').removeClass('is-visible');
        passwordtext = true;
        } else {
            loginPass.addClass('has-error').next('span').addClass('is-visible');
            passwordtext = false;
                    //console.log("NO");
        }



        if (logintext == true && passwordtext == true){
            console.log("Both");
            return true;
        } else {
            console.log("Missing");
            return false;
        }



    });
```

**Old Login.php for reference**

```
<?php

session_start();

?>

<?php


//Log out and delete cookie
  if(isset($_GET['logout'])){
            session_destroy();

  }

//After validation, then check the entered data  
  if( isset($_POST['log_username']) && isset($_POST['log_password'])) {


    $log_username = $_POST['log_username'];
    $log_password = $_POST['log_password'];

    $con =mysql_connect("localhost", "user4321", "4321");
    mysql_select_db('supernatural',$con);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_username='$log_username' AND user_password2='$log_password'";
    $sql_E = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_username='$log_username'";

    $loginShow = mysql_query($sql);
    $loginShow_E = mysql_query($sql_E);

    $lookOver=mysql_num_rows($loginShow);
    $lookOver_E=mysql_num_rows($loginShow_E);

    $row = mysql_fetch_array($loginShow);
    $row_E = mysql_fetch_array($loginShow_E);

    $myuser = $row['user_fn'];
    //$cookie_name = "cook_name";
    if($lookOver == 1){ 
            //Set Cookie for 1 day
            //setcookie($cookie_name,"$myuser", time() + 86400,"/");
            $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
            $_SESSION['user'] = $myuser;
            $_SESSION['userid'] = $row['user_id'];
            $_SESSION['userlevel'] = $row['level'];

            header("location: map.php");



            /*
if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
                echo "Cookie name does not exist!";
                } else {
                    echo "Cookie is named: <br>" . $_COOKIE[$cookie_name]."<a href='?logout'>Log Out</a>";

                    }
*/


        } else {
            //If only password is wrong, then it will send an email with password.
            if($lookOver_E == 1){

                echo "Don't remember your password? </br> <a class='refound_P' href='register.php'>Register a new account with a new email</a>";
                /*href='found.php '>Send me a email with my password.</a>";   */      
            //If there is not one data relevant to, then it requires users reset.
            }else{
                echo "</br>Don't remember your Username? </br> <a class='refound_E' href='register.php'>Register a new account with a new email</a>";

            }

            }


    mysql_close($con);

  }

  //echo json_encode($_SESSION['loggedin'] ? 'true' : 'false');


?>


<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.finvisionconsultants.com/images/login_key.png">
    <link href='css/style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="validation2.js"></script>
    <title>Login</title>
    <style type='text/css'>
    body{background-color: #575757;}
    input {padding: 5px 10px;font-size: 15px;}
    button {padding: 5px 10px;border-radius: 0px;}
    .erroB {border: 1px solid #ec9acd;}
    .msg {font-family: fantasy;color: #ec9acd;}
    #msgBox{}
    h1{color: green;}
    .refound_P,.refund_E{color: #8480d4;}
    form{margin-left: 35%;margin-top: 10%;}
    .main{font-size: xx-large;color: white;}
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="col-lg-6" id="logo-area">
        <img src="images/mainTitle.png" alt="Supernatural Guide Map">
    </div>
    <form action="login.php" method="post">

        <table>
           <tr id="msgBox">
                <td colspan="2"><p class="msg"></p></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label>Username</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="log_username" name="log_username" />
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label>Password</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="password" id="log_password" name="log_password" />
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>

        <button type="submit" id="submitBtn">Log In</button>



    </form>
    <button style="margin-left:35%; margin-top:7px;" onClick="location.href='index.php'">Cancel</button>

<div id="status">

</div>



</body>

</html>
```

**Old validation2.js (equivalent to what main.js does above) for reference**

```
$(window).load(function() {

        $('#submitBtn').click(function() {
                return validate();   
        });

        //Assign two functions for acting displaying message and removing it
        function displayMsg(msg) {
            $('.msg').html(msg);
        }

        function clearMsg() {
            $('.msg').html("");
        }

        function validate() {

            var loginUsername = $('#log_username');
            var loginPass = $('#log_password');
            //the rule of validating letters and email format
           // var emailRegex = /^\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$/;
            //Login validation:Email
            //if (emailRegex.test(loginEmail.val())) {
            if (loginUsername.val() != 0){
                loginUsername.removeClass("erroB");
            } else {
                loginUsername.addClass("erroB");
                displayMsg("Please check your username");
                return false;
            } 


           //Login validation:Password
            if (loginPass.val() != 0) {
                loginPass.removeClass("erroB");
            } else {
                loginPass.addClass("erroB");
                displayMsg("Password is required");
                return false;
                }

            clearMsg();
            return true;

        }
       //make the validation be immidiatelly.
        $('input').keyup(function() {
            validate();
        });

 });
```

I have only tried with getting the login part (not the register) working to start but even this is not doing anything.

I've basically copied exactly what I had from the previous login but cannot work out why it is not working! All of the database credentials are correct. 
Am I missing something really simple here?

Comment: Please, [don't use `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php), They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://us1.php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://us1.php.net/mysqli). [This article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide.

Comment: What error messages are you getting?

Comment: @isim none, thats the problem. I don't know what's going on!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the queries are not  being processed. You don't have the name attribute in the login form. Add the `name="log_username"` and `name="log_username"` in the form and then the `$log_username =  $_POST['log_username']` and `$log_password = $_POST['log_password']` will have values.

Also in the form action leave it empty and the form will submit it to itself.  Do the same, adding name attributes, for all the input fields in the login form and the register form.

Here is the fix for the login form:

```
         div id="cd-login"> <!-- log in form -->
            <form class="cd-form" action="" method="post">
                <p class="fieldset">
                    <label class="image-replace cd-username" for="log_username">Login</label>
                    <input class="full-width has-padding has-border" id="log_username" name="log_username" type="text" placeholder="Username">
                    <span class="cd-error-message">Please enter a username!</span>
                </p>

                <p class="fieldset">
                    <label class="image-replace cd-password" for="log_password">Password</label>
                    <input class="full-width has-padding has-border" id="log_password" name="log_password" type="password"  placeholder="Password">
                    <span class="cd-error-message">Please enter a password!</span>
                </p>

                <p class="fieldset">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="remember-me" checked>
                    <label for="remember-me">Remember me</label>
                </p>

                <!--p class="fieldset"-->
                    <input class="full-width" id="submitBtn" type="submit" value="Login">
                <!--/p-->
            </form>

            <p class="cd-form-bottom-message"><a href="#0">Forgot your password?</a></p>
            <!-- <a href="#0" class="cd-close-form">Close</a> -->
```